# HMAC SHA 256 decode/encode issues

Tags: vb.net, arduino, sha, arduino-ide, hmacsha1

Hey all I am trying to figure out why my HAC-SHA-256 encryption and decryption is not matching up from my Arduino code to my .net code:

C# code:

```
Dim message As String = "Hi There"
Dim expectedHex As String = ""

TextBox1.Text = (Convert.ToString("Ref : ") & expectedHex)

'Test out the HMAC hash method
Dim key As String = "61574d6b157f757d02457573556645750e0341481b127a07476303136c005145436c7b46651c6e4f4f040e1569464a794e534309097258550c17616075060950"
Dim hashHMACHex__1 As String = HashHMACHex(key, message)

TextBox2.Text = (Convert.ToString("HMAC: ") & hashHMACHex__1)

' Test out the SHA hash method
Dim innerKey As String = "61574d6b157f757d02457573556645750e0341481b127a07476303136c005145436c7b46651c6e4f4f040e1569464a794e534309097258550c17616075060950"
Dim outerKey As String = "0b3d27017f151f17682f1f193f0c2f1f64692b227178106d2d096979066a3b2f2906112c0f760425256e647f032c2013243929636318323f667d0b0a1f6c633a"
Dim hashSHAHex__2 As String = HashSHAHex(innerKey, outerKey, message)

TextBox3.Text=(Convert.ToString("SHA : ") & hashSHAHex__2)
```

Arduino code:

```
char *myData = "61574d6b157f757d02457573556645750e0341481b127a07476303136c005145436c7b46651c6e4f4f040e1569464a794e534309097258550c17616075060950#(128)";

void printHash(uint8_t* hash) {
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<32; i++) {
    Serial.print("0123456789abcdef"[hash[i]>>4]);
    Serial.print("0123456789abcdef"[hash[i]&0xf]);
  }
  Serial.println();
}

uint8_t* hash;
  uint32_t a;
  unsigned long ms;
  Serial.println("Test: RFC4231 4.2");
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Result:");
  ms = micros();
  Sha256.initHmac((uint8_t *)myData,128);
  Sha256.print("Hi There");
  printHash(Sha256.resultHmac());
  Serial.print(" Hash took : ");
  Serial.print((micros() - ms));
  Serial.println(" micros");
  Serial.println();
```

The output from the .net program is this:

> HMAC: 2d484b68dae3866fbcbf182071c3bf5e86f40ab6c2f3bc72d69fe0d132bf771e
>
> SHA : 5929bc8b6968e763c7f23090f7d6194c4f1377bd8f6e4b781a5ecdb8e8f91f8f

And the Arduino output:

> Result:9a9f6119b41604441db0a75bad6c4e1653a4d00781d4b177e99fe850ad543051

I'm not sure what **innerKey** and **outterKey** is in the .net program. That may be the cause of me not getting the correct values?

[Attached](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=464844.0;attach=204997) is the full code for both the .net program and the arduino sketch.

Comment: The code is VB.NET

Comment: Oops.. correct. Thanks @xanatos

Comment: [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code)-SHA 256 is not encoding nor encryption and thus can not be decoded. it is an Hash-based message authentication code and designed not to be able to be reversed. It is like putting you phone in a blender, you can never get the phone back together.

Comment: @zaph One must first ask "will it blend?"

Comment: Ah yes, "will it blend?", see [Blend a Samsung Galaxy](https://youtu.be/izHLC173MTs). BTW, Apple actuallyy hashes it's Cloud Key Vault admin smart cards in a blender, see [Physical One-Way Hash Function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLGFriOKz6U&feature=youtu.be) at 34:06.

Comment: What hash function is used in HashHMACHex()?  Often HMAC has sha1 under the covers, but your Arduino code uses SHA256.  This could be the problem.  As for the inner key and outer key stuff, I suggest you do not use that code: that looks like NMAC to me rather than HMAC, and NMAC is almost never used in practice.